# JNI java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError,cannot link method

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I have seen a lot of questions of UnsatisfiedLinkError and I know what my problem is. I get

***Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Test.initCamera(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)J***

This means the dll has been loaded but it cannot find the method. However, I've checked my source code and java code. The method name and arguments are all right. I don't know what's wrong with my code.

Here are my codes.

Java:

```
public class Test {
public native long initCamera(String ip,String port,String username,String pwd); 
public native int snapPic(long id,String savePath,int no);
static{
    System.loadLibrary("dhconfigsdk");
    System.loadLibrary("dhnetsdk");
    System.loadLibrary("dhplay");
    System.loadLibrary("CameraCatcher");
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Test tNative = new Test();
    String ip="192.108.1.108";
    String port="37777";
    String username="admin";
    String pwd="123456";
    long cameraId=tNative.initCamera(ip,port,username,pwd);
    System.out.println(cameraId);
    String savePath="D:/";
    int number=tNative.snapPic(cameraId,savePath,0);
}
}
```

C++:

```
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_CameraCatcher_initCamera
(JNIEnv * env, jclass c, jstring arg_ip, jstring arg_port, jstring arg_username, jstring arg_pwd)
{
    ......
    return lLogin;
}


JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_CameraCatcher_snapPic
(JNIEnv * env, jclass c, jlong arg_id, jstring arg_path, jint arg_no)
{
    .....
    return 12;
}
```

This really drives me crazy.

**Update 1:**
Thanks for everyone's reply. I've changed my code just as @Mr Tarik showed.

Java:

```
public class CameraCatcher {
    static{
         System.loadLibrary("CameraCatcher");
    }
    public native long initCamera(String ip,String port,String username,String pwd);
    public native int snapPic(long id,String savePath,int no);
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        CameraCatcher tNative = new CameraCatcher();
        String ip="192.108.1.108";
        String port="37777";
        String username="admin";
        String pwd="123456";
        long cameraId=tNative.initCamera(ip,port,username,pwd);
        System.out.println(cameraId);
        String savePath="D:/project/j2ee/Example/result";
        int number=tNative.snapPic(cameraId,savePath,0);
    }
}
```

Then I use javah to generate header file:

```
#include <jni.h>

#ifndef _Included_CameraCatcher
#define _Included_CameraCatcher
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     CameraCatcher
 * Method:    initCamera
 * Signature: (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)J
 */
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_CameraCatcher_initCamera
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jstring, jstring, jstring, jstring);

/*
 * Class:     CameraCatcher
 * Method:    snapPic
 * Signature: (JLjava/lang/String;I)I
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_CameraCatcher_snapPic
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jlong, jstring, jint);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

C++ code:

```
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_CameraCatcher_initCamera
(JNIEnv * env, jobject c, jstring arg_ip, jstring arg_port, jstring arg_username, jstring arg_pwd)
{
    return 1;
}
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_CameraCatcher_snapPic
(JNIEnv * env, jobject c, jlong arg_id, jstring arg_path, jint arg_no)
{
    return 2;
}
```

I compile this code and get new dll.
However it still has the error as before.......

**Update 2:**
Yes.It works. I don't know why the function definition code changed in my .cpp file. I just changed the jclass to jobject as EJP told me the problem yesterday.Maybe it has been changed since yesterday by chance and I didn't observe. It's all my carelessness. Thanks for everyone again.

The problem is exactly what EJP said. I generated the file with static function but make it work in a non-static way. Another problem is that I generated the class CameraCatcher while I used the class Test.

Comment: You've changed the method from `static` since you generated the `javah` file.

Comment: @EJP I'm still not clear. Could you explain it more detailedly? What should I do?

Comment: Err, regenerate the .h file? And adjust your method signature accordingly?

Comment: Sigh. You have `Java_CameraCatcher_initCamera` in the .h file, and `initCamera` in the .cpp file. These still do not agree. Similarly for `snapPic`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code. you need to edit functions names in c++ you need to have something like this

```
    #include "test.h"
    #include <jni.h>

JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_CameraCatcher_Test_initCamera
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject  obj, jstring ip, jstring port, jstring username, jstring pwd){

    return 1.0;
}
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_CameraCatcher_Test_snapPic
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jlong id, jstring savePath, jint no){
    return 5;
}
```

dont forget the name of your class Test to add it in `Java_CameraCatcher_Test_snapPic`.

**edit 1:**
this is what i have in header:

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class CameraCatcher */

#ifndef _Included_CameraCatcher
#define _Included_CameraCatcher
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     CameraCatcher
 * Method:    initCamera
 * Signature: (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)J
 */
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_CameraCatcher_initCamera
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jstring, jstring, jstring, jstring);

/*
 * Class:     CameraCatcher
 * Method:    snapPic
 * Signature: (JLjava/lang/String;I)I
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_CameraCatcher_snapPic
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jlong, jstring, jint);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

c++:

```
#include "cameracatcher.h"
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_CameraCatcher_initCamera
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject  obj, jstring ip, jstring port, jstring username, jstring pwd){

    return 1.0;
}
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_CameraCatcher_snapPic
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jlong id, jstring savePath, jint no){
    return 5.5;
}
```

Java:

```
public class CameraCatcher {

    public native long initCamera(String ip, String port, String username, String pwd);

    public native int snapPic(long id, String savePath, int no);

    static {
        System.load("/home/tarik/NetBeansProjects/Testc++/dist/test.so");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        CameraCatcher tNative = new CameraCatcher();
        String ip = "192.108.1.108";
        String port = "37777";
        String username = "admin";
        String pwd = "123456";
        long cameraId = tNative.initCamera(ip, port, username, pwd);
        System.out.println(cameraId);
        String savePath = "D:/";
        int number = tNative.snapPic(cameraId, savePath, 0);
        System.out.println(number);
    }
}
```

All works fine.

Comment: CameraCatcher is my class name. I use default package.

Comment: it's not the case in your code here.
I recommande you to regenerate the header and take the same methods names and their parameters.

Answer (score 1):

The Java class that contains the native methods is named **Test**. But you generated the C++ header for class named **CameraCatcher** (in default package).

You can either rename the Java class, or change the C++ function to `Java_Test_initCamera` and `Java_Test_snapPic`. Don't forget to define these functions as `extern "C"` (we usually do that in header file, generated by **javah**).

Answer (score 0):

THe JNI method names need to follow a convention.
The method names can be generated using built-in tools that come with JDK.

Please see this link for more details.
https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html

Comment: The method name is generated automatically.I didn't change it.

Comment: But you changed the source code it was generated from.

Comment: @EJP I just fill in the content of main function of the source code. This doesn't  make any difference for .h file it generates.Right now, I  used the code the same as the above Java code to generate the header file. But it still doesn't work. Maybe I don't understand what your point is.

Comment: A static JNI function has `jclass` as the second parameter. A non-static has `jobject`. Your C++ code has `jclass` but your Java code doesn't have `static`. You had `static` when you ran `javah` and you have subsequently removed it. Or your C++ code never agreed with the generated .h file in the first place.

Comment: @EJP Thanks for your explanation. I now understand what you mean. However, I've tried  using non-static functions and regenerate the dll. It still has this problem.

Comment: Then you have some other disagreement. What you write in the C++ code must agree exactly with the generated .h file, and that in turn must agree exactly with the Java code via regeneration. Every time you change the Java code you have to regenerate  the .h  and readjust the C++.